# Power() function and COLUMN_UPDATED() function in SQL server

Tags: sql-server, triggers

what does below line mean in SQL server 2008 triggers?

```
(SUBSTRING(COLUMNS_UPDATED(),2,1)) = power(2,(6-1))
```

Comment: If only there was a way to find the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186329(v=sql.110).aspx) that includes examples of how it's used.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever It's all very well pointing to the documentation, but what we really need is some kind of website that could allow us to find it. A "find machine" or something.

Comment: I thought I understand how this column testing works, but now I find I don't. I just asked a [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18098798/substring-and-hex-value) because of it.