# SUBSTRING() and hex value

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

How does substring work on hexadecimal values?

See this:

```
PRINT SUBSTRING(0x6,1,1)
PRINT SUBSTRING(0xF6,1,1)
PRINT SUBSTRING(0xFF6,1,1)
PRINT SUBSTRING(0xFFF6,1,1)
```

...outputs...

```
0x06
0xF6
0x0F
0xFF
```

...which currently looks as a complete nonsense to me. But it can somehow used in detecting which column is updated in trigger ([see COLUMNS_UPDATED()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186329%28v=sql.110%29.aspx)).

I tried:

- intermediately converted it to string and then substring it
- intermediately converted it to int, then string and then substring it
- searching in MSDN substring() documentation
- googling

Can someone explain how is that conversion done?

Comment: Complete nonsense? Surely it's just the leftmost complete byte?

Comment: @AakashM: :D, yes, I seem to really missed that! 0xFF6 => 0x**0**FF6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`SUBSTRING` documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx) isn't particularly clear about how it treats binary values, referring to 'characters' rather than bytes. But it's effectively treating the input as a byte sequence, and with `1, 1` you are asking for the first byte of the sequence:

```
Input    Byte sequence
----------------------
0x6      06
0xF6     F6
0xFF6    0F F6
0xFFF6   FF F6
```

Output of `SUBSTRING(input, 1, 1)` :

```
0x06
0xF6
0x0F
0xFF
```